# Which default formats does GeoServer REST API datasource PUT endpoint accepts?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm using the following endpoint to create datasources in Geoserver:

`PUT /workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{storeName}/{method}.{format}`

I have been able to create `vector` datastores from an already available `.shp` at Geoserver data directory, using the `method` as `external` and  `format` option as `.shp`

My issue is that [the documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/datastores.yaml) only gives the `.shp` format example, and i can't seem to find whats the correct option for `geotiff` format.

So, does any one know the list of available options for `format` and the correct way to use it for `geotiff` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geotiff is not a "datastore" but a coveragestore instead.
See: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/coveragestores.yaml

Comment: Thanks, just test it and works like a charme! By the way, sorry for the follow up question, but is there any way to get all datastores and coveragestores for a given workspace? Or do i have to use the two endpoint? thanks.

Comment: The two endpoints